# Create output-agnostic markup for fontcolor in RMarkdown documents

Tags: css, r, lua, r-markdown, pandoc

I try to achieve a convenient markup, that will change the font-color for some words for both pdf and html output.

Currently I use sth like

```
 This word is __<span style="color:green">green</span>__
```

which produces the desired output, when rendered to html-output. Unfortunately, this markup is very verbose and doesn't work for pdf-output.

Ideally, I would be able to define sth like `[green]{.green}` and use css or [lua-filters](https://ulyngs.github.io/blog/posts/2019-02-19-how-to-use-pandoc-filters-for-advanced-customisation-of-your-r-markdown-document/) to style the respective output-documents.

I also set up a minimal exampe repo on github, which summarises my attempts so far: https://github.com/henningsway/rmd_semantic_markup/blob/master/Q.Rmd

Comment: yes, `[green]{.green}` is a valid pandoc markdown span, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans and https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html for how to change that for non-html outputs.